The type or namespace name 'WindowsAppSDK' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
I have added Nuget 'Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" as shown below

However when adding the library in App.xaml.cs:
using WASDK = Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK;

It gives an error:

The type or namespace name 'WindowsAppSDK' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)



Did I miss any steps?

I would suggest first specifying what you need to use and then look for that class/interface on their github repo

@MichałTurczyn Yes, but I see it used exactly like above in this project: https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/2965bc4d81aba72966f49c5fd5809c34bb13af94/WinUIGallery/App.xaml.cs#L23. So I think I had a problem adding the library.

Check items in Visual Studio Installer -> Individual components and  ensure that all SDKs matching your development environment are installed.

Try to add version info to your .csproj file:
<WindowsAppSdkIncludeVersionInfo>true</WindowsAppSdkIncludeVersionInfo>

